# Embeding shared links

Tags: box-api

I am using shared links on my site to show boxnet folder, for example:

**https://www.box.com/embed_widget/000000000000/s/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx**

I am trying to customize the order and theme color of the folder being shown by using:

**https://www.box.com/embed_widget/000000000000/s/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?sort=date&direction=DESC&theme=gray**

The problem is that i am not seeing any changes on it.

Does somebody know what i am doing wrong? May be i am not using the correct parameters.

Thanks in advance,

Kind Regards,

Marcelo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marcel,

Here is some documentation on how to set the styling parameters. If testing in the browser, you'll need to reset the session to see your styling changes by using the additional parameter session_expired=yes.

http://developers.box.com/0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661/

We may make some slight changes to this, but this mostly how it will work. Direction=asc or desc should work too.

Rory